# SQL Join Statement + COUNT doesn't work

Tags: oracle, group-by

Here is my SQL (Oracle) code:

```
SELECT a.Task_id, a.Activity_desc AS "ACTIVITY DESCRIPTION" ,
       a.Activity_date || ' (' || a.Activity_day || ')' AS "ACTIVITY DATE",
       pr.Project_name, COUNT(a.Volunteer_id)
FROM task_activity a
JOIN task t
ON a.Task_id = t.Task_id
JOIN project pr
ON t.Project_id = pr.Project_id
GROUP BY a.Task_id
ORDER BY Task_id
```

An error :

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Without group statemen table looks like that :

[image]

I want to count number of volunteers for each task and group by task_id, but after hours of tries I gave up )

Comment: Why select `pr.Project_name`?

Comment: By definition anything not in the group by IN YOUR SELECT STATEMENT must either be in a Distinct clause, or an aggregate function. Since you are grouping by the task_ID, how are you assigning the other columns?

Comment: Do you want to count volunteers by task_id, or by task_id AND date? If only by task_id, then there is no way to include anything that has to do with "date" in the result, in any meaningful way. (Do you want to show the first and the last date for that task_id? THAT can be done.) Other than that: assuming every task_id belongs to only one activity_desc and only one project_name (otherwise again what you are trying to do doesn't make sense), - so, if every task_id belongs to only one activity_desc and project_name, add activity_desc and project_name to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please note the tags at the bottom of your post. They are added by StackOverflow automatically, and almost always they are wrong. You need to select the proper tags as part of your posting a question. I will go ahead and "edit" your post to delete the sql-server tag. You can always to that yourself (both to "edit" your question and specifically to "edit" the tags). One more thing - in your questions always include your Oracle version, often the right answer depends on which version you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by all non aggregated values.  Start off with something small and build up e.g.

```
SELECT a.Activity_desc, COUNT(a.Volunteer_id) countVolunteer
FROM task_activity a
GROUP BY a.Activity_desc
```

Check that returns you a count per activity, and then slowly add your other attributes to both the SELECT and GROUP BY sections e.g.

```
SELECT a.Activity_desc, t.Task_id, COUNT(a.Volunteer_id) countVolunteer
FROM task_activity a
JOIN task t
ON a.Task_id = t.Task_id
GROUP BY a.Activity_desc,t.Task_id
```